# .htaccess generic mod_rewrite rules

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, apache2

I have a site where I am trying to change the urls using mod_rewrite from:

`/directory/filename.php` to `directory/filename/`

`/directory/filename.php?id=7` to `directory/filename/7/`

`/directory/filename.php?id=7&file_id=1` to `directory/filename/7/1/`

I am not able to  work out the regular expressions to use for these pages though. Here is the entire .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On    # Turn on the rewriting engine

RewriteRule  ^(.*)/?$ /directory/$1 [L] #Rewrite a page without $_GET variables
RewriteRule  ^([^/]+)/([0-9]+)/?$ /directory/$1?id=$2 [L] #Rewrite a page with 1 $_GET variables
RewriteRule  ^([^/]+)/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/?$ /directory/$1?id=$2&file_id=$3 [L] #Rewrite a page with 2 $_GET variables
```

Comment: is the .htaccess in the `directory` or the `root` folder?

Comment: You mean the other way around, that you want to rewrite (the request) **from** `foo/bar/` **to** `foo/bar.php`?

Comment: foo/bar/ will be the url in the browser but foo/bar.php will be the file name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the `.htaccess` is in the `directory` folder then the `directory/` path prefix will be stripped for you and you do not need to bother about it in the rewrite rules.

You could use something like:

```
RewriteEngine On    # Turn on the rewriting engine

RewriteRule  ^([^/.]+)/?$ $1.php [L] # rewrite without query string parameters
RewriteRule  ^([^/.]+)/(\d+)/?$ $1.php?id=$2 [L] # one parameter
RewriteRule  ^([^/.]+)/(\d+)/(\d+)/?$ $1.php?id=$2&file_id=$3 [L] # two parameters
```

Comment: That's brilliant! Thanks Qtax :)

Comment: @ThinkingMonkey's point about the [QSA] flag is important because some of the mapped URIs might have request parameters and without this, Rules 2 and 3 will loose them.  The OP probably doesn't want this to happen. But a +1 subject to this :)

Comment: @TerryE, I see, but we don't really know if that's what OP wants, so I didn't add it. (It can easily included by adding `QSA` to the flag list.)